# Redirect users to authorization URL with request parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to redirect users of my web application to an authorization endpoint (a third party) with request parameters from within my site.  I'm using asp.net core as my technology platform.

Do I do this sort of thing inside of the middleware pipeline or in an api/mvc controller?

Right now i'm trying to do it inside of a controller. I can create a call and get back the response, but I don't really think i'm suppose to render their response. Here's my code:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "somevalue"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "somescope"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("state", "fizzbuzz"));
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(authorizeEndPoint, content);
```

I'm at a loss here and for some reason can't wrap my mind around the solution.  How am I suppose to redirect my users to be authorized with a third party?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to get it working by changing my ActionResult to void and inside my action adding

```
   [HttpGet]
    public  void Index()
    {
        Response.Redirect("url?client_id=value&scope=value&state=value");
    }
```

I'm still not sure if this is correct practice or should I be handling the redirect inside of my middleware.  I'm not sure but this works, but is it right?  Hope this helps someone else in the future, and I hope someone can validate if this is right or not.